# Java spring time of instants elapsed in assertEquals statement

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, assertion

I have some tests in my testsuite that run on all my colleagues, but fail on me. And that is to return two times from different entities in the form of an instant and compare them with each other. They actually match, but not for me.

This is the described line:

```
assertEquals(notUpdatedRule.getModStamp(), rule.getModStamp());
```

As error message I get back the following:

```
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: 
Expected :2023-01-22T19:46:20.754829Z
Actual   :2023-01-22T19:46:20.754829486Z
```

I have already tried to adapt my openjdk version to that of my colleagues, but this has not changed anything.

Comment: Does any of the code depend on the execution duration? Is anywhere an actual timestamp of the system used where the test is run on? (e.g. with `Instant.now()`)

Comment: How do you assign those timestamps? I remember something of different methods leading to differences in resolution of the timestamp.

Comment: @cyberbrain Instant.now() is used for the getModStamp()

Comment: I recommend that you use `Instant.now(Clock clock)` instead. From its [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html#now(java.time.Clock)): "Using this method allows the use of an alternate clock for testing."

Answer (score 1):

I recommend that you use `Instant.now(Clock clock)` instead. From its [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html#now(java.time.Clock)): "Using this method allows the use of an alternate clock for testing."

The problems could arise from different time zones, different operating systems, different hardware precision of timers in your systems etc.

When you specify a `Clock` you could create that with a defined precision (milliseconds, seconds, minutes or any other `Duration`) for your tests.

Or you could provide a `Clock` that always returns the same instant for your tests (which I really would recommend to have reproducible tests!) with `Clock.fixed(Instant fixedInstant, ZoneId zone)`.

For production use, you can simply provide a `Clock.systemUTC()` to have the current behaviour of `Instant.now()`.
[`Clock`s JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Clock.html) explain the reason for using it in more detail.